# Including ASPX file on a page via AJAX - viewstate error on post back only with IE

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.Net web app which has a page with various GridViews shown in Jquery tabs. This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but the page is slow to render in IE. So I thought instead of loading all the gridviews at once, i'll just load them as and when the user clicks on a tab.

So I have set up a new aspx page which accepts parameters of what to show. This all works fine in all browsers and the page is now nice and fast in IE.

However, IE has come to bite me again, because as soon as the page hits a postback it generates this exception:

**The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.**

From what I can understand this is because the GridView control that is loaded via AJAX has to be inside a `<form>` tag with runat="server" and this is changing the viewstate of the overall page. So when it postbacks the original page it seems to have lost its viewstate.

I then tried to turn off the viewstate in the aspx being included. Via `EnableViewState="false"` but this still doesnt work.

I'm confused how Chrome and Firefox are ok, but only IE is getting the ViewState error. Is there anything else I can do to ensure the sub-page does not alter the ViewState in IE?

Perhaps if ASP.Net didnt detect the browser as being IE, it wouldnt do whatever it is doing to break the page?

Comment: Do you have any console (I mean browser's developer console) error?

Comment: Nope - nothing logged to the developer console :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the `enableEventValidation` attribute in the web.config file for the asp.net application to false.

If using IIS6, make sure IIS compression is turned off.

If is possible, add `OnClientClick` event to button, that cause the postback, and call a function that removing added controls via `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, after lots of research I don't think what I was trying to do is possible.

As a work around I opted to insert an iFrame within the jQuery tabs, and then load the gridview in that. This then doesnt upset the viewstate of the parent page.